# Uploading the files and folders using Go to the box account

Tags: go, box-api

For the program below I get the below error. It will be helpful if anyone helps me to fix my errors. Thanks in advance.

```
func upload() {
    fmt.Println("dfxfgcghvjbjhiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii")
    apiUrl := "https://upload.box.com/"
    resource := "api/2.0/files/content"
    data := url.Values{}
    data.Add("access_token", accessobj.Access_token)
    authbear := "Bearer "
    authbear += accessobj.Access_token

    u, _ := url.ParseRequestURI(apiUrl)
    u.Path = resource
    urlStr := fmt.Sprintf("%v", u)
    client := &http.Client{}
    fmt.Println(urlStr)

    f, err := ioutil.ReadFile("C:\\Users\\vembu\\Desktop\\hi.txt")
    ioutil.WriteFile("hi.txt", f, 0x777)
    r, _ := http.NewRequest("POST", urlStr, bytes.NewBuffer(f))
    r.Header.Add("Authorization", "Bearer "+accessobj.Access_token)
    r.Header.Add("attributes",
        "{\"name\":\"hi.txt\",\"parent\":{\"id\":\"3098791209\"}}")
    r.Header.Add("file", "hi.txt")
    fmt.Println(r)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error......:", err)
    }

    resp, err1 := client.Do(r)
    if err1 != nil {
        fmt.Println("error:", err1)
    }
    fmt.Println("uploading")
    fmt.Println(resp)

    re, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("errorrrrr:", err)
    }
    fmt.Println(string(re))
}
```

I get the following error:

```
I face &{405 Method Not Allowed 405 HTTP/1.1 1 1
map[Allow:[GET, OPTIONS, HEAD] Content-Type:[text/html;charset=UTF-8]
Content-Length:[0] Date:[Thu, 12 Mar 2015 13:07:32 GMT] Age:[0]
Connection:[keep-alive]
Server:[ATS]] 0xc08200b8c0 0 [] false map[] 0xc08201f2b0 0xc082060980}
```

Comment: As trivial as your code seems to be, please apply some formatting on it...

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you try to do an `HTTP POST` request:

```
r, _ := http.NewRequest("POST", urlStr, bytes.NewBuffer(f))
```

But the server does not allow/support this as stated in the response error (only `GET`, `OPTIONS` and `HEAD` methods are allowed):

> Method Not Allowed 405 HTTP/1.1 1 1 map[Allow:[GET, OPTIONS, HEAD]

According to the [box.com API](https://developers.box.com/get-started/) to upload a file using `POST` you need to use a multi-part form upload request.

You can use the [`multipart`](http://golang.org/pkg/mime/multipart/) package to create a multipart request with a file.

Here is an example how to do it (incomplete/untested code):

```
buf := &bytes.Buffer{}
mw := multipart.NewWriter(buf)
defer mw.Close()
f, err := os.Open("C:\\Users\\vembu\\Desktop\\hi.txt")
if err != nil {
    // Handle error
}
defer f.Close()
ff, err := mw.CreateFormFile("name", "hi.txt")
if err != nil {
    // Handle error
}
if _, err = io.Copy(ff, f); err != nil {
    // Handle error
}

// TODO: INCLUDE OTHER FIELDS/PARAMS IN URL
r, err := http.NewRequest("POST", "https://upload.box.com/api/2.0/files/content", buf)
if err != nil {
    // Handle error
}
r.Header.Set("Content-Type", mw.FormDataContentType())
// TODO: ADD YOUR OTHER HEADER FIELDS

// Do the call: upload file
client := &http.Client{}
resp, err := client.Do(r)
if err != nil {
    // Handle error
}

if resp.StatusCode != http.StatusOK {
    fmt.Printf("Error: %v", resp.Status)
}
```